# How to display Scanned SonarQube Branches in Jenkins UI

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-scan

I'm using SonarQube Enterprise 8.7 and running scans with it via Jenkins and I'm wondering if there's an option or parameters within SonarQube to have the name of my scanned branches displayed in the Jenkins UI.

This image is an example of what I'm after

[image]

The names have been blurred out but you can see the name **digital** which forms part of the branch name.

It seems to work straight out of the box with older versions of SonarQube, but not with newer versions.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I just needed to add this to my Jenkinsfile and it works.

`currentBuild.description=$BRANCH_NAME`